# geom_density plots with nested vectors

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data frame with a nested vector in one column.  Any ideas how to `ggplot` a `geom_density` using the values from the nested vector?

If I use `pivot_longer` the entire data frame, I get 25 million rows, so I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:5],length.out = 100), b = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T))
df[["c"]] = purrr::map(1:100, function(x) rnorm(100))
# works but too heavy for the actual implementation
ggplot(tidyr::unnest(df, c), aes(c, group = a)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(vars(b))
# doesn't work
ggplot(df, aes(c, group = a)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(vars(b))
```

Comment: What's your goal? To plot the total density or the density by group in `a`? Should all density curves belong to one or separate plots? Please edit your original post to clarify.

Comment: ```ggplot() + geom_density(aes(unlist(df$c)))```

Comment: Goal is to plot density by group in a, facet wrap across b.  Original post edited.

Answer (score 0):

Different solution: Prepare each plot separately and rearrange your plots afterwards using `gridExtra` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:5],length.out = 100), b = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T))
df[["c"]] = purrr::map(1:100, function(x) rnorm(100))

lst_plot <- lapply(sort(unique(df$b)), function(x){
  data <- df[df$b == x,
  data <- purrr::map_dfr(seq(length(data$a)), ~ data.frame(a = data$a[.x], c = data$c[.x][[1]]))
  gg <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_density(aes(c, group = a)) +
    ylab(NULL)
  return(gg)
})

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = lst_plot, ncol = 6, left = "density")
```

To be honest, I'm not sure how well this works with your massive dataset...

Comment: Thanks.  As I mentioned in the original post, my actual data would turn into a dataframe 25 million lines long if I pivot_longer.  i.e., turn the 3rd line of code into df[["c"]] = purrr::map(1:100, function(x) rnorm(250000)).  So, trying to avoid that if possible.